# Calling JS function freezes react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a certain number of images on a screen for my app in React Native .53.3. I pass the number of images I want (they are identical images) through the navigator and then in turn pass that prop onto a javascript function that generates top/left coordinates for the images randomly.

Here is where it all goes wrong: The screen is unreachable. The button on the screen proceeding it doesn't work -- it won't even register a press -- and so the screen with the images never renders.

If I insert a return statement before the while-loop, the script functions fine and I'm able to even navigate to the image screen. So I think this problem is somehow related to the loop. I'm a bit of a JS newbie but I think my code all looks nice and correct... 
Here is the script in question:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
export function barGeneration(n) {

var barCoords = [];
var noZone = [{
    x: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
    y: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2
}];

while (barCoords.length < n) {
    var left = ((Dimensions.get('window').height) - 101) * Math.random();
    var top = (Dimensions.get('window').width - 101) * Math.random();
    var validX = true;
    var validY = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < noZone.length; i++) {
        if (left > noZone[i].x - 101) {
            validX = false;
        }
        else if (left < noZone[i].x + 101) {
            validX = false;
        }
        if (top > noZone[i].y - 101) {
            validY = false;
        }
        else if (top > noZone[i].y + 101) {
            validY = false; 
        }
    }

    if (validX && validY) { 
        barCoords.push({
            top: top,
            left: left,
            rot: Math.random()*360 + 'deg'
        });
        noZone.push({
            x: left,
            y: top,
        });
        validX = false;
        validY = false;
    }
}
return barCoords;
}
```

And here is where the script is called:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // assigning constant coordinate values to junk bars
    var barCoords = barGeneration(this.props.navigation.state.params.n);
    this.setState({barCoords: barCoords});
```

Navigation from the non-functioning button:

```
<Button
    raised
    backgroundColor='#CCC'
    color='black'
    iconRight={{name: 'arrow-right', type: 'feather'}}
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PracticeTrial2', {n:2, count:0, scores:[]});}
    title='Start Practice: Memory for 2 items'
/>
```

Comment: First, I would test if it is the actual script causing the freeze or if `this.setState({ barCoords })` is causing a bunch of components to render and cause the freeze. I would comment out the `setState` call and run it. If it freezes, then you know you need to make `barGeneration` more performant . If it doesn't, then you need to look at what all components get re-rendered when `this.state.barCoords` gets updated. Your `barGeneration` code looks good and I don't think that would cause an issue unless `n` was a really big number (in the thousands).

Comment: And now that I look at it, you may need to constrain the random number here: `((Dimensions.get('window').height) - 101) * Math.random();` to be something in a more realistic range. You should log how many times `if (validX && validY) ` fails so you can see how many wasted cycles your script is running.

Comment: After seeing your usage in the edit, I'm almost positive that it is my second suggestion. The random number you generate is too large and it is causing way too many fails. You should only give a random number between 0 and max screen size.

Comment: You're absolutely right... My math was clearly off. I was thrown off that the script failed seemingly before it was called. Thanks a ton!